# CSS element with fractional percent height still takes up space in flex container

Tags: css

I have an image element that I'm trying to maintain aspect ratio of.  I need it to have responsive width.  In other words, the image needs to have 100% width but always have height *relative* to its responsive width.  i.e. the width always needs to be 100% of the parent container (which is using flex) and the height always needs to be 56% *of the width*.  This is what I've tried:

```
#container {
  display: 'flex',
  alignContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  justifyItems: 'center',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 0, 2),
}

#myImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56%;
}

<div class='container'>
  <img class='myImg' src='whatever.jpg'>
  <div ... other stuff />
</div>
```

The problem is that this *does* maintain the aspect ratio as desired, but adds a gap above the image and below the "other stuff", according to the full height of the image if it weren't set to 56%.  How do I achieve this without the gaps?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach:

Use an `outer wrapper-div` for the image. Grant aspect ratio by `padding-top`. Position image in the wrapper by `position: absolute`, center it and hide parts which are larger than aspect ratio if image does not match aspect ratio on its own.

See example/demo:

```css
#container {
  display: 'flex',
  alignContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  justifyItems: 'center',
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 0, 2),
}



.img-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 56%;   
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.img-wrapper img {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>

    <div class="img-wrapper">
        <img class='myImg' src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/0000ff/fff&text=-image-'>
    </div>

</div>
```